# Stop NW.js from trying to connect to the internet

Tags: node-webkit

I'm creating a simple offline hobby app, that doesn't use the internet for anything, using NW.js.

Although nowhere in my app is there any call to the internet, my firewall tells me `nw.exe` keeps trying to connect to the internet every time I run the app.

Is there a way to stop NW.js from making any calls to the internet?

I looked up the IP, it's apparently calling Google, I imagine this must be something from Chromium.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be something Chromium does, rather than NW.js. But since NW.js is built on top of Chromium it inherits it.

Some related GitHub issues:

- https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/5343
- https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/5865

One suggestion is to add the following to the `package.json`:

```
"chromium-args": "--proxy-server=http://127.0.0.1"
```

This will prevent any external network calls from working. Which sounds like what you want. Give it a try, if it does not work and you have additional information, you should contribute to those GitHub issue threads.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and well researched answer! It's still making calls, but I think they're now all redirected to localhost. To be extra safe, this is my `chromium-args` now:  `"chromium-args": "--proxy-server='http://127.0.0.1' --disable-background-networking --host-rules='MAP * 127.0.0.1'"
` (btw, disable-background-networking seems to make no difference)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this seems to be a well known issue for many years: https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/5865 . It's still an open issue.

As per the Github thread, apparently adding switches to `chromium-args` in the manifest doesn't work anymore. I tried adding them manually when starting the app in the command line, it also didn't work. My list of switches is quite ridiculous at this point: `"chromium-args": "--proxy-server='http://127.0.0.1;https://127.0.0.1' --disable-sync --disable-background-networking --disable-component-update --host-rules='MAP * 127.0.0.1' --disable-http-cache --disable-http2 --disable-ntp --disable-renderer-backgrounding --disable-sync --disable-features=NetworkService"`.

The **good news** is that it seems all calls are being redirected to localhost, but I can't confirm since I set my firewall to block all of them from completing (I don't know what they'd do if there was a response). Unfortunately, I don't think there's a solution right now, which is a dealbraker for me.